Converting HTML to Jira markup using only regex
I'm using a tool that doesn't have any specific HTML parsing capability. It does have regex replace functionality (based on the Boost library), and I'm able to use that to convert a lot of the formatting. I understand that it's imperfect, but it's "good enough".
Lists are proving a bit trickier. I know that I could use some script code to iterate through these, but given the power of regular expressions, I feel that it should be possible.
My input can contain something like this:
<p>Numbered bullet list:</p>
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<p>Standard bullet list:</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
    <li>Item D</li>
</ul>

And I'd like to convert this to:
Numbered bullet list:
    # Item 1
    # Item 2
    # Item 3
Standard bullet list:
    * Item A
    * Item B
    * Item C
    * Item D

I already have a first pass that will remove the paragraph tags, so these can be ignored for the purpose of this question. If I only have one list type, I can do a simple replace of the list tags. Is it possible to do the conversion for text containing both list types using only regexes?
Thanks!

Why you shouldn't parse HTML with a Regex.

@0stone0 OP said: I'm using a tool that doesn't have any specific HTML parsing capability. So you are right, but that will not help OP

@0stone0 Absolutely understand that it's not a great idea, but it's for comments that use HTML syntax for formatting rather than decoding full HTML documents. I have limited options, and for most of the other conversions regex is working sufficiently well.

I understand, just sharing to show the Technical difficulties with doing this.

I mean ... technically this is possible, but the problem here is that you might not know how many items you have.
You could do something like
<ol>([\s\w<>/]+)<li>([^<]+)<\/li>
and replace that with
<ol>$1# $2
if you execute that n times (whatever arbitrary number this is), you would have basically the first list done.
The same goes with the <ul>: replace <ul>([\s\w<>/]+)<li>([^<]+)<\/li> with <ul>$1* $2
After that you have something like this:
<p>Numbered bullet list:</p>
<ol>
    # Item 1
    # Item 2
    # Item 3
</ol>
<p>Standard bullet list:</p>
<ul>
    * Item A
    * Item B
    * Item C
    * Item D
</ul>

Then you can remove the start and end tags of the lists.
PS: replacement syntax ($1) might vary depending on the tool you use

I had the idea in my head that regexes had some form of iterative capability that would cope with performing this for an arbitrary number of entries in a single operation. It's not a total dealbreaker to have to do the iteration at the script level...

Not as of my knowledge.
You could execute the replacement like 20 times, nothing will break if you execute it more often than needed (pattern is simply not found anymore), but once there is something with > 20 entries it might not look that good anymore.
But yes, it is possible to do so :)
